# SQL Server : get all data from one table but condition on 2nd tables column

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

I have 3 tables `Student`, `Classes` and `StudentClasses`.

**Student** table:

[image]

**Classes** table:

[image]

**StudentClasses** table:

[image]

What I am trying is

```
select 
    c.ClassID, sc.StudentID, Title, 
    ClassFrom as ClassDate, ClassTo as ClassTime,
    Duration, Type as SessionType, sc.Status as StatusJoin
from 
    Classes c 
left join 
    StudentClasses sc on sc.ClassID = c.ClassID 
where 
    sc.StudentID = '66919287-d63d-4b30-931f-30532b68c2f1' or 
    sc.StudentID IS NULL
```

This returns:

[image]

Which is correct I think, but when I change it to:

```
where sc.StudentID = '5a22f025-ae64-49b8-9782-32bc2f1ccef6'
```

this returns:

[image]

This should return all 4 classes with studentID and joining date null

Here is the question: I want here is all classes rather some student joins or not if joins then there should be Studentid and JoiningDate there other wise these columns can be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your condition in ON Clause instead of Where

```
 select c.ClassID,sc.StudentID,Title,ClassFrom as ClassDate,ClassTo as 
       ClassTime,Duration,Type as SessionType,sc.Status as StatusJoin
       from Classes c 
       left join StudentClasses sc on sc.ClassID = c.ClassID 
       and (sc.StudentID = '66919287-d63d-4b30-931f-30532b68c2f1' or 
       sc.StudentID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

select c.ClassID,sc.StudentID,Title,ClassFrom as ClassDate,ClassTo as 
       ClassTime,Duration,Type as SessionType,sc.Status as StatusJoin
       from Classes c 
       left join StudentClasses sc on sc.ClassID = c.ClassID

Would also help!!!